# Who said "He'd back over his grandmother in an Olds Ninety-Eight"?

Tags: united-states

I am trying to recover the details of a quote a friend of mine used to repeat that went something like:

*"He'd back over his grandmother in an Olds Ninety-Eight"*

referring to politicians being willing to do anything for money. I think it dates from the 50's or 60's?

I've tried quite a few different Google searches and I'm coming up empty handed. Anybody recognize the statement? Who said it, when, in reference to who?

I would love to read the real details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribution is not clear, but possibly related to Charles Colson in the early 1970's, with further embellishment to what was actually said.

[Charles Colson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Colson#%22The_%27Evil_Genius%27_of_an_Evil_Administration%22)

> Colson authored the 1971 memo listing Nixon's major political opponents, later known as Nixon's enemies list. A quip that "Colson would walk over his own grandmother if necessary" mutated into claims in news stories that Colson had boasted that he would run over his own grandmother to re-elect Nixon.

The unmutated quote was attributed to "an unnamed former member of Senator Saltonstall’s staff".

> Chuck Colson left the Saltonstall senatorial office after the 1960 election and founded a law firm that represented corporate interests in Washington. From 1969 to 1973 he served as special counsel to President Nixon where, according to Leverett Saltonstall, “Colson’s loyalty to another led him into difficulties.” In fact, when the *Wall Street Journal* introduced Colson to the public as “Nixon’s hatchet man” who handled the president’s “dirty work,” they quoted an unnamed former member of Senator Saltonstall’s staff who stated that “Chuck Colson would walk over his own grandmother if he had to”—the pattern of his later behavior already had been set. This vivid description later morphed into “Colson would “run over his grandmother if necessary to elect Nixon” (eliciting angry mail from grandmothers), but in the face of much criticism in the press, Colson rather gleefully admitted that the original quotation was “absolutely accurate.” [Massachusetts Historical Society](http://masshist.org/database/viewer.php?item_id=2046&pid=3)